# On open and click JS style - panel1 not taking on style

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

Ok so I finally have managed to get *most* of this working. 
I have a script that changes the color of my panel-title on click / open. 
However, i am having a problem with accordions with more than 4 panels.

To recreate the problem: open another panel, you will see that panel1 is still using the grey panel-title background. Click on another panel, and you will notice panel1 NOW uses the correct style.
Why can i not get panel1 to turn back to white the FIRST time it's closed?
Thanks in advance.

```js
var selectIds = $('#panel1,#panel2,#panel3,#panel4,#panel5,#panel6,#panel7,#panel8');
$(function ($) {
    selectIds.on('show.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).prev().find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
    });
    $(".panel-heading").find("a[data-toggle=collapse]").on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
            $(this).closest('.panel-group').find('.panel-default').removeClass('open');
            $(this).closest('.panel-default').addClass('open');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.panel-default').removeClass('open');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.panel-default.open {
  background-color: #616161;
  transition: all 1s;
  }
  .custom-panel .panel-default.open >.panel-heading {
  background: transparent;
          color:#fff;
  }
       .custom-panel .panel-default>.panel-heading {
         background: #fff;
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
       </head>
 <body>
  <div class="panel-group custom-panel" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default open">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle collapsed text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1">
                                <i class="fa fa-minus text-primary"></i> CONTENT
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
             CONTENT
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> CONTENT</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
            CONTENT
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> CONTENT</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
                       CONTENT
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel4"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> CONTENT</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="panel4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
                CONTENT
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel5"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> CONTENT</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="panel5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
                 CONTENT
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel6"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> CONTENT</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="panel6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
        CONTENT
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel7"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> CONTENT</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="panel7" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
            CONTENT
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="thin accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel8"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> CONTENT</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="panel8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
                CONTENT
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add class `open` to the first header with `panel-default` in your html.
It will display the correct class on pageload.

```js
var selectIds = $('#panel1,#panel2,#panel3,#panel4,#panel5,#panel6,#panel7,#panel8');
$(function ($) {
    selectIds.on('show.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).prev().find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
    });
    $(".panel-heading").find("a[data-toggle=collapse]").on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
            $(this).closest('.panel-group').find('.panel-default').removeClass('open');
            $(this).closest('.panel-default').addClass('open');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.panel-default').removeClass('open');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.panel-default.open {
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
  }
  .custom-panel .panel-default.open >.panel-heading {
  background: transparent;
  }
       .custom-panel .panel-default>.panel-heading {
         background: #fff;
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
       </head>
 <body>
  <div class="panel-group custom-panel" id="accordion">
   <div class="panel panel-default open">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>Panel 1</a>
     </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
     <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 1</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Panel 2</a>
     </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 2</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Panel 3</a>
     </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 3</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel4"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Panel 4</a>
     </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panel4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 4</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Kim! I can't believe i missed that.

Question - I'm using Chrome (so it may be browser related), it seems that if i click away from the default open panel, the red style remains on the panel-title (even though its closed & should be white) until I click open a few other panels. Is there anything that can be done for that? It doesn't do it on my accordion with 4 panels, but does it to the one with 8.

Comment: @becca I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. I assume that you have a click listener on document or another parent element that you click to close the dropdown. In that case you have to remove the class `open` as well when you do.

Comment: @becca I don't have this problem. if you try the code snippet above, you'll see it works as you intend...

Comment: Kim, please see my edited above snipped (in question). I have added details there about the problem happening. I have added info on how to recreate.

Comment: @becca did you change something else? I just copy pasted your previous code, added `open` and it worked. I suggest that you just copy-paste the code I shared with you, which as you can see, works. Not that I don't want to help you, but I figure that it's going to take more time finding out what the problem with your new code is; I think it's probably something small.

Comment: Kim, I am using the code you gave me - this is only pertaining to accordions with more than 4 panels. Your code works great, except for when i have more than 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113756/discussion-between-becca-and-kim-gysen).